# Merge two different structs

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two structs named as "Invoices", "Transactions". These are GORM models. I wanna merge these structs and convert json.

**Example:**

```
type Invoice struct {
     gorm.Model
     DocType string `json:"docType"`
     Total float64 `json:"total"`
}

type Transaction struct {
     gorm.Model
     DocType string `json:"docType"`
     Total float64 `json:"total"`
     Account uint `json:"account"`
}
```

I wanna response like;

```
[
{docType:"invoice", total: "123.00"}
{docType:"transaction", account:"1", total: "124.00"}
{docType:"invoice", total: "125.00"}
]
```

Comment: Put them in an array and marshal: `x:=[]interface{}{invoice,transaction,invoice,transaction}, json.Marshal(x)`

Comment: Is it possible ? `x:=[]interface{}{[]invoice,[]transaction}, json.Marshal(x)`

Comment: That is wrong syntax. You don't have arrays within arrays.

Comment: But these getting from database. How can I adapt your solution to GORM models ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. If you get an invoice and a transaction from the db, you can get the JSON you want using `[]interface{}{inv,tr}` where `inv` and `tr` are structs you retrieved from the db.

Comment: I tried, its working well but not exactly what I want. It results `[[{docType:"transaction", account:"1", total: "124.00"}
], [{docType:"invoice", total: "123.00"}, {docType:"invoice", total: "125.00"}]]`
I wanna objects in one array

Comment: If that is the output, then `inv` and `tr` are arrays, not individual structs. Create an `[]interface{}` and append elements of `inv` and `tr` to that array.

Comment: `var docs []interface{}, for _, x := range invoices {docs = append(docs, x)} for _, x := range transactions {docs = append(docs, x)}` Its worked, thanks! Are there a better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the response you list in your question you can use a generic array `[]interface{}` and turn that into JSON.

```golang
inv1 := Invoice{
    DocType: "invoice",
    Total:   123.00,
}
inv2 := Invoice{
    DocType: "invoice",
    Total:   125.00,
}
tran := Transaction{
    DocType: "transaction",
    Total:   124.00,
    Account: 1,
}
bytes, _ := json.Marshal([]interface{}{inv1, tran, inv2})
fmt.Println(string(bytes))
```

It doesn't matter whether you fill the structs with values from gorm or you just initialize yourself them as I do here.

---

Reading the comments, it appears that you have two slices of structs and you want to merge the two into a single slice, and then encode to JSON.

You can do that like this:

```golang
arr1 := []Invoice{inv1, inv2}
arr2 := []Transaction{tran}

combined := make([]interface{}, 0, len(arr1)+len(arr2))
for i := range arr1 {
    combined = append(combined, arr1[i])
}
for i := range arr2 {
    combined = append(combined, arr2[i])
}
bytes, _ := json.Marshal(combined)
fmt.Println(string(bytes))
```

Here again, I'm just using slices I created myself, but these could easily have come from gorm's `db.Find(&arr1)`.

Comment: Thanks! Its working. But, what is differences are `make([]interface{}, 0, len(arr1)+len(arr2))` and `var combined []interface{}` ? Are there any difference ?

Comment: The difference is one of performance: the `make` call creates a slice with a pre-allocated capacity which I set equal to the number of elements I expect to add. When I then add elements, it won't need to resize the underlying memory which results in faster code. This only makes a significant difference when the size of the arrays is large.

Comment: That was a nice explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, no worries :)